# Edge split modifier is not working at all

Tags: edges

In this tutorial (https://youtu.be/71WnmX1UrEk?t=425), the creator smooths out his table tennis bat by either using the Edge Split modifier.

I'm using Blender 3.15 (or similar), and I can't get this modifier working at all - my edges are not smoothed. All the other modifiers, such as Subdivision surface, screw, etc, work just fine.

Doing this on Object data properties > Normals > Auto smooth, doesn't work either.
Any idea why this might be? I can't smooth out other shapes either, such as the monkey head, as shown.

[image: edge split not working]

Comment: It works fine for me, have you right-clicked > Shade Smooth? Could you please share the object that has Edge Split but is not smoothed?

Comment: Try `Object` menu -> `Shade Smooth`

Comment: Fixed it - as you said, what mattered was the order in which you do it - as in: Right click > Shade Smooth, then > Object data properties > Normals > Auto Smooth    . Thank you, @rooobertek

Comment: and thank you also to @moonboots  !